# cygwin bash not waiting for background scripts to finish

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, wait, background-process

I've encountered an issue with waiting for background jobs; I have two scripts set up with the following basic structure:

**Main script:**

```
cat list_of_names.txt | while read name; do

  ./my_script_1.sh $name &

done

wait

./other_process.exe
```

**my_script_1.sh:**

```
name=$1

./prog_1.exe $name
./prog_2.exe $name
./prog_3.exe $name
```

The program `other_process.exe` can only be run once all the backgrounded instances of `myscript.sh` have finished running. The problem is that the call to `wait` doesn't wait for these background processes to finish, instead the main script immediately runs `other_process.exe` (which fails).

While attempting to debug this,  I have found that calling `jobs` within the `while` loop correctly displays all of the background instances of `myscript.sh` that are running. However, calling `jobs` outside of the loop just before the `wait` command returns nothing. As far as I can tell, once the main script has finished the `while` loop it can no longer see any of the child processes that were started by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't cygwin specific. The pipe in bash starts its commands in subshells. Therefore, the background processes are children of the subshell, not the main shell. Avoid the pipe, replace it with the process substitution `<( ... )`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x ; do
    ( echo Start $x ; sleep $x ; echo Done $x ) &
done < <( echo $'1\n2' )
echo Done start
wait
echo Done all
```

Comment: Thanks, process substitution did the trick! I wasn't sure whether it was cygwin-related, so I mentioned it just in case that had anything to do with it.